# Swift: Combine condition and if-let with logical or

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

I am trying to do something that would logically look like this:

```
if text == "" || let i = Int(text) where i < 2 {
   // do something; don't care about the value of i
}
```

Of course this isn't a valid condition -- what would the value of `i` be if `text == ""` is the part that holds? But, since I'm only interested in the value of `i` inside the `where` clause, I was hoping there is a nice way of achieving the same effect, namely executing the same closure if either condition holds. My current solution is to extract the closure and call it from two separate `if` blocks, but that's pretty hairy-looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent to your code example would be:

```
if text == "" || Int(text) ?? 2 < 2 {
    print("valid")
    // do your previous "something
} else {
    print("invalid")
}
```

which yields

> "" -> valid
>   "1" -> valid
>   "2" -> invalid
>   "abc" -> invalid

Comment: Uh, "abc" prints `valid` because `nil < 2`.

Comment: @vacawama correct :/ Fixed it, now it is no longer as pretty.

Comment: Clever! And if I need a more complex condition on the right-hand side (I do), any "invalid" number will do after the `??`.

Comment: @PBosman if you need more complex conditions you are probably not going to fit them into a single line inside the if-construct. the `??` part is there to circumvent the problem that vacawama pointed out: if `Int(text)` returns nil, then it is "replaced" with `2`, otherwise the actual return value is used. That way the comparison with 2 always yields the correct result.

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing this kind of comparison regularly, you could create your own operator in order to compare an optional with a given closure representing your condition for success. If the unwrapped value meets the condition, it'll return true – else false.

For example:

```
infix operator ?& {precedence 130 }
func ?&<T>(lhs: T?, @noescape rhs:(T)->Bool) -> Bool {
    return lhs != nil ? rhs(lhs!) : false
}

...

if text == "" || Int(text) ?& {$0 < 2}  {
    print("valid")
} else {
    print("invalid")
}
```

You could also overload the existing `<` operator to do this, but this may impact already existing code that relies on `nil` being less than a non-optional value.

```
func <<T:Comparable>(lhs: T?, rhs:T) -> Bool {
    return lhs != nil ? (lhs! < rhs) : false
}

...

if text == "" || Int(text) < 2  {
    print("valid")
} else {
    print("invalid")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a more "Swifty" way to handle optional values is with `map`. Essentially, `map`ping an optional value gives you an unwrapped value in your closure, which you can then modify to return what you need. Outside the closure, you will receive either the modified value, or nil if the original optional was nil.

```
let optInt: Int? = 1 // or nil
let incremented: Int? = optInt.map { $0 + 1 }
// If optInt isn't nil, its incremented value is returned by map.
// If it is nil, map just returns nil.
```

So to solve my problem, I could do:

```
if text == "" || Int(text).map({$0 < 2}) ?? false {
   // If text has an Int value, the map closure will return
   // whether that value is less than 2.
   // Else, map will return nil, which we coalesce to false.
}
```